# Disord.py system_channel.send

Tags: discord.py

How can I send a message to the system message channel?
Error:
***AttributeError: module 'discord.guild' has no attribute 'system_channel'

I don't want to send message with channel ID

```
@Bot.event
async def on_message_edit(before, after):
.
.
.
    await discord.guild.system_channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`discord.guild` is not the way you should be calling the guild, as this does not specify what guild you are trying to access. Instead, you can use either `before.guild` or `after.guild`, as these are [message objects](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_message_edit#discord.Message). Do view the revised code below.

```py
@Bot.event
async def on_message_edit(before, after):
.
.
.
    await before.guild.system_channel.send(embed=embed)
```